# Unable to move files in storage container to archive storage in Azure

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm struggling to move some files/folders from the cool tier in a container into archive storage.  I've a load of machine backups that I want to get migrated over.

I've got the files in a container that's set to private and I know I need to select each of the files individually and change the properties to archive.

The problem is that when i go into the properties of the file, hot an cool (inferred) are available but archive is greyed out.

Anyone any ideas?  Followed a couple of articles below but no matter what I'm unable to get them over to archive storage.

https://www.techtalkcorner.com/move-files-archive-tier-azure-storage/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: Archive storage is not supported in all regions, where is your account located?

Answer (score 0):

That's it.  Not available in the region.

Thank you Joel